# How to make the node version of lessc or recess compile with development output for FireLESS

Tags: javascript, node.js, less, development-environment

The following is code that can be used for the browser/live version of less. But how can I do this for the command line version?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     less.env = "development";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. The lessc compiler compiles Less code into static CSS code.

When running Less in the browser as explained http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser the Less code will be compiled with the less.js compiler. The less.js runs client side in your browser and can send message to the console (which can be read by FireLess).